# Multiplicar las filas de una matriz con números para cada unas con numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Quiero escribir una función que tome dos argumentos, (1) una matriz de n x m y (2) una matriz de 1 x n, y que multiplique cada fila por el índice correspondiente de la matriz de escala.

Por ejemplo, f(A, [3, 10]), operaría sobre una matriz A de 2 x m y multiplicaría cada elemento de la primera fila por 3 y la segunda por 10.

```
import numpy as np


def dot_product(matrix, scaler):
    '''function that takes two arguments, (1) an n x m matrix and (2) a 1 x n matrix, 
    and that multiplies each row by the corresponding index of the scaling matrix.'''
    assert(len(matrix)==len(scaler))
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        matrix[i]=np.array(matrix[i])*scaler[i]
        
    return matrix

A = [
        [12, 7, 3], 
        [4, 5, 6]
    ] 
  
# take a 3x matrix 
B = [3, 10]

print(dot_product(A, B))
```

Devuelve:

```
[array([36, 21,  9]), array([40, 50, 60])]
```

Pero es mejor utilisar numpy, vero? Lo intento con numpy:

```
def dot_product2(matrix, c):
    matrix = np.array(matrix)
    c = np.array(c)
    print(c)
    return matrix * c
```

Pero cuando lo hizo con:

```
print(np.array([[12, 7, 3],[4, 5, 6]])*np.array([3, 10]).T)
```

Me devuelve:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 28, in <module>
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,3) (2,)
```

Comment: Agrega un ejemplo con matrices y resultados.

Comment: `np.einsum("ij,i->ij", A,B)`

Comment: También `(a.T*b).T`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solución simple

No estabas lejos con tu intento de usar `*`, sólo que las dimensiones de las matrices no eran las correctas para intentar la operación.

Sean:

```
A = np.array([[12, 7, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
B = np.array([3, 10])
```

Debido a que A es de dimensión 2x3 pero B es de dimensión 2, no pueden ser multiplicadas (pues debe coincidir la segunda dimensión de A con la primera de B). Usar `B.T` no arregla nada, porque al ser `B` un vector, la operación `T` (traspuesta) lo deja igual.

Sin embargo sí funciona `A.T`, pues así pasa a ser de 3x2. Entonces:

```
>>> A.T*B
array([[36, 40],
       [21, 50],
       [ 9, 60]])
```

Lo cual es casi lo que querías, salvo que el resultado está traspuesto. Por tanto basta transponerlo otra vez:

```
>>> (A.T*B).T
array([[36, 21,  9],
       [40, 50, 60]])
```

### Solución más compleja

En este caso no tiene mucho sentido usar esta solución, pero es mucho más flexible y permite ser usada en otros problemas en los que necesites multiplicar entre sí matrices, vectores o incluso tensores (matrices de matrices) de formas complicadas.

Consiste en usar `numpy.einsum()` que utiliza la [notación de Einstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) para expresar de forma muy compacta qué índices de cada matriz participan en los sumatorios y productos necesarios.

No voy a entrar en detalles sobre la notación de Einstein (yo mismo no la tengo del todo clara y acabo dando con la fórmula correcta un poco por ensayo y error), pero en este caso sería así:

```
>>> np.einsum("ij,i->ij", A,B)
array([[36, 21,  9],
       [40, 50, 60]])
```

La "fórmula mágica" es la expresión `ij,i->ij` que viene a decir que el resultado (`->ij`) tendrá dos índices y por tanto será una matriz bidimensional, que se creará iterando por los dos índices `ij` de la primera matriz, pero sólo por un índice `i` de la segunda. En esa iteración se irá calculando el producto de cada elemento de la primera matriz por cada elemento de la segunda, y se irán sumando (acumulando) estos elementos si fuera necesario. En este caso no lo es porque la matriz resultado es también bidimensional, pero si fuera unidimensional, por ejemplo si hubiéramos puesto `->i` entonces se sumarían de forma que desapareciera el índice `j` y por tanto se sumarían por filas, saliendo:

```
>>> np.einsum("ij,i->i", A,B)
array([ 66, 150])
```

Mientras que si hubíeramos usado `->j`, el índice que debería desaparecer sería el `i`, por lo que se sumaría por columnas:

```
>>> np.einsum("ij,i->j", A,B)
array([76, 71, 69])
```

Es más, si eliminas ambos, te suma todos:

```
>>> np.einsum("ij,i->", A,B)
216
```

Answer (score 0):

Para operar con matrices en Python, Numpy es posiblemente la mejor opción. Para este caso, te sugiero trabajar en todo momento con matrices.

Para que los elementos cada fila de una matriz se multipliquen por números establecidos, se pueden hacer uso de distintas formas. Una de ellas es la siguiente:

```
def producto(A, B):
    # Comprobar que tengan el mismo número de filas, y que B solo tiene una dimensión
    assert A.shape[0] == B.shape[0] and B.ndim == 1
    nueva = np.copy(A)
    for columna in range(A.shape[1]):
        # Multiplicar cada columna, elemento a elemento, por la matriz B que proporciona los factores de multiplicación
        # Usando el operador * lo que aplica es multiplicación de matrices
        nueva[:,columna] = np.multiply(A[:,columna], B)
    return nueva
```

Utilizando el ejemplo que proporcionas:

```
>>> A = [[12, 7, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> B = [3, 10]
>>> # Convertir a matrices/arrays Numpy
>>> A = np.array(A)
>>> B = np.array(B)
>>> producto(A, B)
array([[36, 21,  9],
       [40, 50, 60]])
```